# Fitting "multimodal" lognormal distributions to data using python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have the following data measured using an instrument in the lab. Since the instrument collects particles of different sizes in bins based upon their diameter the measurements are essentially "binned":

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from lmfit import models

y = np.array([196, 486, 968, 2262, 3321, 4203, 15072, 46789, 95201, 303494, 421484, 327507, 138931, 27973])
bins = np.array([0.0150, 0.0306, 0.0548, 0.0944, 0.1540, 0.2560, 0.3830, 0.6050, 0.9510, 1.6400, 2.4800, 3.6700, 5.3800, 9.9100, 15])

bin_width=np.diff(bins)
x_plot = np.add(bins[:-1],np.divide(bin_width,2))
x=x_plot
y=y
```

[image]

When plotted here is how the data look. There is one mode around 0.1 and another mode around 2 in the units of the x-scale.

Within this research area it is common to fit "multimodal" lognormal distributions to such data: Given this I have fitted the mode around 2 using LMFIT:

```
model = models.LognormalModel()
params = model.make_params(center=1.5, sigma=0.6, amplitude=2214337)

result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As expected this results in a good fit for the second mode around 2. My question is how would I also go about fitting a second mode around 0.1 (essentially a sum of the two modes should fit the data)? I realise it could also be argued that three modes would be better but I assume once I understand how to use two modes, the addition of a third should be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lmfit.Models` can be added together, as with:

```
model = (models.LognormalModel(prefix='p1_') +
         models.LognormalModel(prefix='p2_') +
         models.LognormalModel(prefix='p3_') )

params = model.make_params(p1_center=0.3, p1_sigma=0.2, p1_amplitude=1e4,
                           p2_center=1.0, p2_sigma=0.4, p2_amplitude=1e6,
                           p3_center=1.5, p3_sigma=0.6, p3_amplitude=2e7)
```

In a composite model, each component of the Model gets its own "prefix" (any string) that prepends the parameter names.  You can get a dictionary of a Models components after the fit with:

```
components = result.eval_components()
# {'p1_': Array, 'p2_': Array, 'p3_': Array}
for compname, comp in components.keys():
    plt.plot(x, comp, label=compname)
```

For fitting data that you would represent on a semi-log or log-log plot, you might consider fitting a model to `log(y)`.  Otherwise, the fit will not be very sensitive to misfit at very low values of `y`.

Note that `lmfit` models and parameters support bounds.  You may want to or find that you need to place bounds such as

```
params['p1_amplitude'].min = 0
params['p1_sigma'].min = 0
params['p1_center'].max = 0.5
params['p3_center'].min = 1.0
```

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your comments. With regards lmfit, I assume it is possible to get at the final parameters somehow (to use down the line)?

Comment: One other question - if I log transform the data as you suggest I assume there is a way that I can transform the fit parameters back to the original untransformed data. I had assumed I would just need to do an exp() of the amplitude of each mode but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @user1912925 the best-fit parameters will be in `result.params`.   If you fit `log(y)`, the fitted parameters will be to model that... Coincidentally, if you are fitting `log(y)` you can fit GaussianModels to that (as pointed out in the other answer), and the `amplitudes` will be the strengths (or areas) of each component.    That's what I would start with...

Answer (score 1):

This is a log-normal mixture distribution you're trying to fit. You can simply take the log of your data and fit a gaussian mixture instead:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# Make data from two log-normal distributions
# NOTE: 2d array of shape (n_samples, n_features)
n = 10000
x = np.zeros((n,1))
x[:n//2] = np.random.lognormal(0,1, size=(n//2,1))
x[n//2:] = np.random.lognormal(2,0.5, size=(n//2,1))

# Log transform the data
x_transformed = np.log(x)

# Make gaussian mixture model.
# n_init makes multiple initial guesses and
# depending on data, 1 might be good enough
# Decrease tolerance for speedup or increase for better precision
m = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, n_init=10, tol=1e-6)

# Fit the model
m.fit(x_transformed)

# Get the fitted parameters
# NOTE: covariances are stdev**2
print(m.weights_) # [0.50183897 0.49816103]
print(m.means_) # [1.99866785, -0.00528186]
print(m.covariances_) # [0.25227372,0.99692494]
```