# Fit “multimodal” lognormal distributions using R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

My question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034668/fitting-multimodal-lognormal-distributions-to-data-using-python) but I want to do it in R. The data frame is

```
x<-c(0.35,0.46,0.60,0.78,1.02,1.34,1.76,2.35,3.17,4.28,5.77,7.79,10.50,14.20,19.10,25.80)
y<-c(32.40,43.00,37.20,26.10,17.40,14.00,19.90,36.90,48.60,55.30,64.60,70.20,63.90,47.60,22.70,10.30)

df<-data.frame(x,y)
plot(df,log='xy')
```

[image]

When plotted here is how the data look. There is one mode around 0.5 and another mode around 8 in the units of the x-scale.

How do I fit "multimodal" lognormal distributions to such data (In this case with 2 curves)? Here's what I have tried. Any help or direction to solve it is greatly appreciated.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="nls", 
              formula=y ~ a*dlnorm(x, meanlog=8, sdlog=2.7),
              method.args = list(start=c(a=2e6)), 
              se=FALSE,color = "red", linetype = 2)+
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `nls`. You may consider two modes by defining two parameters in your equation, say `a` and `b`. Define for both the `start=`ing values. (Note, that I just guessed all the values at this time.)

```
fit <- nls(y ~ a*dlnorm(x, meanlog=.5, sdlog=.5) + b*dlnorm(x, meanlog=8, sdlog=2.7),
           data=df1, start=list(a=1, b=1))
summary(fit)
# Formula: y ~ a * dlnorm(x, meanlog = 0.5, sdlog = 0.5) + b * dlnorm(x, 
#     meanlog = 8, sdlog = 2.7)
# 
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# a   -81.97      16.61  -4.934  0.00022 ***
# b 30695.42    2417.90  12.695 4.53e-09 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 11.92 on 14 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.507e-07
```

`fitted()` already gives you the fitted values for `y` along the `x` values of your data frame.

```
fitted(fit)
# [1] 45.56775 44.59130 38.46212 27.34071 15.94205 12.76579 21.31640
# [8] 36.51385 48.68786 53.60069 53.56958 51.40254 48.41267 44.95541
# [15] 41.29045 37.41424
# attr(,"label")
# [1] "Fitted values"
```

You could also use `predict()` for this.

```
stopifnot(all.equal(predict(fit), as.numeric(fitted(fit))))
```

However, to get a smoother line you want a `predict`ion (i.e. `y` values) along a finer set of `x` values along your `x` axis.

```
plot(df1, log='xy')
x.seq <- seq(0, max(df$x), .1)
lines(x=x.seq, y=predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(x=x.seq)), col=2)
```

[image]

<sub>**A sidenote:** Even if this is very common, by naming your data frame `df` you're using the same name that is used for the density function `df()` for the F distribution, which may lead to confusion! For this reason I used `df1`.</sub>

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(0.35, 0.46, 0.6, 0.78, 1.02, 1.34, 1.76, 
2.35, 3.17, 4.28, 5.77, 7.79, 10.5, 14.2, 19.1, 25.8), y = c(32.4, 
43, 37.2, 26.1, 17.4, 14, 19.9, 36.9, 48.6, 55.3, 64.6, 70.2, 
63.9, 47.6, 22.7, 10.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```